# Gummy Bear and Gummy Worm materials

Tags: materials, photorealism

i tried to make realistic material of gummy (jelly ?) but somehow it doesn't look real as i want, I research all over forums and google, like material of Doki on the forums (https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?350580-Gummy-Worms-and-Gumdrop).

Here is what i got:[image]
[image]

What I want to make:
[image]
[image]

Here is my blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzM1zdTMJ5omZVM4alpDLVJRdWs

Comment: [Related](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?350580-Gummy-Worms-and-Gumdrop)

Comment: @batFINGER on my file is actually the node of Doki on the forums. I'll edit in the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is something that looks close.

Please excuse my gummy model, The first picture uses the new *Principled* shader and the second image uses just a glass shader. If you use the glass shader make sure you use a Fresnel and glossy node mixed in.

1. Use the Principled shader with transmission to 1 for glass.
2. In the base color slot connect a color ramp with "constant" selected and choose any colors you would like (this is optional). Also You will need to change from the *Constant* to something else for the Gummy Worm, so it has a nice fall off.

3.Add the *Object Info* node so the computer randomly picks a color.

4.Pick any rough looking texture and plug in into a *Color Ramp* node (so you can control how much you want by sliding the flags). Make sure on the texture image you set it to *Non Color Data* and either unwrap your model or connect the other two mapping nodes so Blender knows where to put the grunge texture.

Just use a texture to have clear and "foggy" sections of the model, and plug it into the roughness socket.

I didn't do it here, but you can grab another texture with divits in it and plug that into the normal socket to add more realism.

[image]

[image]

This is the grunge texture I used.

[image]

Comment: You should probably add something in your answer stating not to download the latest 2.8 build if you are using the model in production or saving important files with it (https://builder.blender.org/download/)

Comment: @icYou520 can you please more detail to the answer? For new users the logic behind your decisions, and the nodes used might not be as obvious, and they won't be able to apply it in other circumstances.

Comment: Thanks you. your node look awesome, btw what kind of textures you using ? i'm change some textures image but if i use some black and white dirt map, it's doesn't effect the model much, if i use some concrete texture that will make the bear too thick.

Comment: ohhh I got it, if my textures too thick or too thin, i can use the the blacknwhith color ramp to get how much dirt i want on the model.

Comment: @cegaton Done,  I added the texture. If this node set up worked for you please mark the answer as accepted, to better help others in the future, and help me get as many points as cegaton. lol

Comment: @icYou520 thanks you for the detail. Help me much in understand how this node working. Love you :D.

Comment: @Squirrel where does he mention 2.8?

Comment: @Neil The "Principled BDSF" Shader will be available in 2.8, however, you can get a test build of 2.79 that also includes it. Same rules apply though.