# Slime effect material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, shaders

[image]

I know the normal + glossy effect but I want the yellow to red color effect by light.

thanks

[image]

this is what I got so far. It kinda looks like the picture but the sss is not emitting the yellow light.

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: maybe try a Subsurface Scattering node? or a mix between Diffuse and Volume Scatter node?

Comment: Look into translucency or subsurface scattering

Comment: The object on the 1st image is not emitting light, so I doubt you need any emission shaders, try translucent or use some volume absorption on connected to the volume socket.

Comment: Realated: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84417/gummy-bear-and-gummy-worm-materials

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Final:

[image: final]

You can also make it with **Principled Shader** only if you like to keep things simple.

### Node setup:

As mentioned above, add **Principled Shader**, set **Subsurface Scattering** to around 0.2-0.3, tweak **Roughness** and you are ready to go.

[image: nodes]

### Scene setup:

For this setup (and reference image) you will need some strong directional light in front of your object. I've used **Area Light**, scaled on X axis.

[image: scene]

Comment: Oh nice! very simple but perfect. thanks for taking your time to answer my question

Answer (score 1):

For the basic setup, add Translucent, Glass and Subsurface Scatter shaders. In the volume section use volume absorption.

[image]

You can then add textures to some of the elements to make the texture less homogeneous.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer!
I've never used the volume node that way before but it looks awesome!

Comment: Volume  absorption is a good tool to add color when dealing with liquids, glass and translucent objects.

Comment: I think you broke the energy conservation with the add shaders, it glows like a lamp.